# Introduction of noise when ADC is active

Tags: adc, noise

To measure 440 VAC, we use a current type voltage transformer as shown on [this webpage](https://www.yuanxing.net/product/Miniature%20Voltage%20Transformers/3.html).

When measured with an oscilloscope, the signal looks good and as expected. However, when I measure the same with an [ADC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc128s102.pdf?ts=1658153784530&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.be%252F), it introduces noise. The noise is present only when the ADC is actively measuring the signal.

The schematic and the PCB design are available at the following links.

Full project:

https://oshwlab.com/sigrama/centinela-tester-20211026_copy_copy_copy_copy_copy_copy_copy_copy_copy

Schematic:

https://easyeda.com/editor#id=4f510cbb25b741928b9f75deb0f9c3a4

PCB:

https://easyeda.com/editor#id=cfa50c9e8d6349088ce558d5928b9370

I think it must have something to do with the type of power supply I am using, which is an [IP5306](http://www.injoinic.com/wwwroot/uploads/files/20200221/0405f23c247a34d3990ae100c8b20a27.pdf).

Measurement:

I am using a `FLUKE 190-504 SCOPEMETER` oscilloscope to measure the output of the op-amp that is connected to the ADC via a filter.

I observed at least three types of noise:

1. A sine wave of 12.5 kHz (approx.) is introduced at an amplitude of 100 mV (approx.) as soon as it is powered on.

[image: sine wave noise at 12.5khz]

2. As soon as I initiate the serial communication on the microcontroller, a higher frequency noise is introduced. However, this noise is not continuous. It appears at a regular interval of 25 μs (approx.).

[image: Regular interval noise when serial communication is enabled]

3. Another noise is observed when I actively measure the ADC. I guess its frequency is the same as the first noise.

[image: Noise observed when ADC is working]

I don't know why any of these noises appear. I guess it must be because of the power supply I am using, which is an IP5306.

Please guide me to eliminate these noises.

Comment: Could you describe better the "noise" you see? **How** do you see it? **Where** exactly ? **What** is different from the non-noisy situation. Of course scope shots would be perfect.

Comment: When you say "However, when I measure the same with an ADC, it introduces noise.", is the noise being measured with the scope on the ADC lines, or are is it being seen in the sampled data?

Comment: Thank you @tobalt and Jonathon S.  I will capture some oscilloscope images and update my question in few hours time.

Comment: Note that in your schematic, you should add a resistor for the positive power supply of the analog part of the converter... I should not wire all the GND and 3.3V analog/digital together... except at the very input supply of the board. Use also if possible a GND large area under the analog part. Keep digital and analog as separated as possible.

Comment: @tobalt, I updated the question with oscilloscope's screenshots.

Comment: @JonathonS. I am measuring at the output of the op-amps, I gave more details in the updated question.

Comment: Not related to the question, but the large copper area below the ESP32 antenna is a really bad idea, detuned. Try to move the module to a boarder and give it some clearance.

Comment: SAR ADC kicks back against the signal whenever Track mode begins (at start of measurement acquisition). Datasheet page 6 shows C_INA Track=33pF, Hold=3pF; so the internal SAR capacitor array presents a 30pF load which is switched on at the start of each measurement. As long as the signal settles to the correct value within the acquisition time (3 SCLK cycles), the ADC measurement won't be affected by this error.

Comment: @MarkU, I think the 3rd noise is not visible in the readings measured by ADC. Thank you. I am not sure because I burned my circuit. I will make another circuit and update. However, the first 2 noises still exist, which are caused be some other reason.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the datasheet ... VA is used also as the reference for the ADC ...

> Positive analog supply pin. This voltage is also used as the reference voltage. This pin should be to VA Supply connected to a **quiet** +2.7-V to +5.25-V source and **bypassed to GND with 1-µF and 0.1-µF**
> monolithic ceramic capacitors located within 1 cm of the power pin.

So it should be "less noisy" as possible, adding also an R-C filter.
Remember that digital supply can be very noisy.
So separate all power supplies, and lastly wire these only at the input supply board pins.
Keep also digital signals away from analog inputs ... GND separation if necessary ...

Please note also this remark in datasheet.

> 9.1 Power Supply Sequence
> The ADC128S102 is a dual-supply device. The two supply pins share ESD resources, so care must be exercised
> to ensure that the power is applied in the correct sequence.
> *To avoid turning on the ESD diodes, the digital supply (VD) cannot exceed the analog supply (VA) by more than 300 mV.*
> Therefore, **VA must ramp up before** or concurrently **with VD**.

And this ...

> 9.2 Power Supply Noise Considerations The charging of any output load capacitance requires current from the digital supply, VD. The current pulses required from the supply to charge the output capacitance will cause voltage variations on the digital supply. If these variations are large enough, they could degrade SNR and SINAD performance of the ADC. **Furthermore, if the analog and digital supplies are tied directly together, the noise on the digital supply will be coupled directly into the analog supply, causing greater performance degradation than would noise on the digital supply alone.**
> Similarly, discharging the output capacitance when the digital output goes from a logic high to a logic low will dump current into the die substrate, which is resistive. Load discharge currents will cause "ground bounce" noise in the substrate that will degrade noise performance if that current is large enough. The larger the output capacitance, the more current flows through the die substrate and the greater the noise coupled into the analog
> channel.

> **The first solution to keeping digital noise out** of the analog supply is to **decouple the analog and digital supplies from each other** or use separate supplies for them.

> To keep noise out of the digital supply, **keep the output load capacitance as small as practical.** If the load capacitance is greater than 50 pF, use a 100 Ω series resistor at the ADC output, located as close to the ADC output pin as practical.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see several mistakes in the design already. Thank you for your answer. I request you to look at the updated question. My doubt is the act of measuring through ADC is changing the signal at the output of the op-amp. Also I observed 3 types of noises, please take a look at it and help me understand what I am missing.

Comment: Do you use all functions of IP5303? It seems a charger/discharger for batteries. So "regulation" of the output voltage is not "essential"? Ripple can be "high", 50 mV, or "more"? "ripple" should depend on the "functional" mode. I should use (or add) another LDO regulator.

Comment: I am using `IP5306`. I am using it to charge/discharge battery. I didn't connect LEDs etc. that would indicate the battery status. Also, the Key functionality of the `IP5306` was not working. I am using `AMS1117-3.3` for the 3V. But 5V is directly taken from the `IP5306`

Comment: Although functionality is not used, ripple is "large". Anyway, I should use an added R-C filter.

Answer (score 2):

You add DC offsets to the OpAmps IN+ path via these resistors: R9, R11, R21, R34. The voltage source of this offset is the noisy 3.3V, attenuated around 100:1 and amplified again a little below 1:50.
So you measure the noise of the 3.3 V supply just divided by 2.

There are only 5 GND vias. Many GND areas are more or less big islands with narrow and complex connections between them. Add 30+ vias to build a proper plane.